# Remove hash and load URL minus hash

Tags: javascript

`enter code here`This JavaScript snippet removes the `/#/and/everything/after` from URL, and reloads the page.

```
var loc = window.location.href,
    index = loc.indexOf('#');

if (index > 0) {
  window.location = loc.substring(0, index);
}
```

As a result, something like this:

```
http://www.somesite.com/#/somepage
```

reloads as this:

```
http://www.somesite.com
```

How can I modify the snippet, to make it remove only this part: `#/`, but keeo everything that comes after it, and load the page at the url that has everything before and after `#/`, like this:

```
http://www.somesite.com/somepage
```

Comment: How does this differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898300/remove-hash-from-url-load-the-page-at-hash-less-url-then-add-hash-to-url-witho?

Comment: If it's trivial for you, @Rakkun, I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, I've just tried the suggestion made by dystroy, because he was kind enough to provide it, and yet for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: It's narrowed down, @DerekHenderson.

Comment: Could tyou please explain to me, @Derek, what should be actually put in that code instead of `"object or string", "Title", "/new-url"` - It points me in the right direction, but I do not understand how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace(/\/#\//, '/');
```

If you only want to reload when there's a #, you can do

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/#/')>=0) {
    window.location = window.location.href.replace(/\/#\//, '/');
}
```

EDIT : to add a # before the last token, you may do this :

```
var href2 = href.replace(/([^\/]+\/?)$/, '#/$1')
```

Examples :

```
"http://www.somesite.com/somepage?a=b" -> "http://www.somesite.com/#/somepage?a=b"
"http://www.somesite.com/somepage/" -> "http://www.somesite.com/#/somepage/"
```

Comment: Why bother with a regex then?

Comment: For some reason it sends a browser into a loop. It never opens the page, but keeps trying.

Comment: @Ian Is it possible to do things without regexes ? Damn...

Comment: @dystroy Oh, I forgot about that. Nevermind... :)

Comment: @KeithRules If you're executing this reloading code each time you load a page, that's perfectly normal. What's your goal ? Do you want to reload only when there's a # ?

Comment: My site uses ajax and has #/ in url, but the href loaded into the page have /regular/directory/structure. mysite.com/somepage actually exists and cam be accessed. I want to remove #/ from URL when a user accesses the page he bookmarked, so that the existing mysite.com/somepage loads instead of non-existent mysite.com/#/somepage.

Comment: @KeithRules, wouldn't it be easier simply to remove the hash from the href?

Comment: That is exactly my question, how can I do that, @Derek?

Comment: @KeithRules Is the edited version what you want ?

Comment: @dystroy, if the url with the hash results in a 404 error, however will the JS be found and executed?

Comment: If you could also show me how to add the hash back into url once the page without the hash has loaded, you'd become my personal hero, @dystroy!

Comment: See edit. If it's not exactly what you want, I think I'll let you tune the last details ;)

Comment: Urgh... ;-( What I meant was, "how to stick the `#/` back into the same place where it used to be, once the page is loaded. I'd understand if you ignore that request, @dystroy, because you'ev already helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

window.location.href.replace("#/","");